# Extract "n" rows for each ID in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, count, member

I have a matrix which has multiple rows per ID.  I need to extract only say..4 LAST rows per ID.  ID cols consists of 2 Cols:

```
mat = [ ...
        2222 1   734771 0.11
        2222 1   734772 0.22
        2222 1   734773 0.33
        2222 1   734774 0.44
        2222 1   734775 0.55
        5555 3   734771 0.11
        5555 1   734772 0.12
        5555 1   734773 0.13
      ] ;
```

answer -->
% [ 2222 1 734772 0.22 ; 2222 1 734773 0.33 ; 2222 1 734774 0.44 ; 2222 1 734775 0.55]

I'll appreciate a vectorized approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a efficient solution using [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) functions:

```
%# sample matrix, sorted by first column
mat = [randi([1 5],[20 1]) (1:20)' rand(20,1)];   %'
mat = sortrows(mat);

%# extract last N rows from each unique ID
N = 4;
[~,~,subs] = unique( mat(:,1) );                 %# index into unique values
fcn = @(x){ x(max(1,end-N+1):end) };             %# at most last N values
ind = accumarray(subs, 1:numel(subs), [max(subs) 1], fcn);
ind = cell2mat( ind(cellfun(@numel,ind) >= 4) ); %# keep only those with 4+ count
result = mat(ind,:)
```

Using the third output of the UNIQUE function, we get for each row the index into the list of unique IDs. Then we distribute the row indices into bins (cell array) based on those subscripts. We take the last four indices from each bin, and filter those with less than 4 occurrences. We then combine them all into one vector of row indices. Finally we use it to get the corresponding rows from the original matrix.

Using the example above, we generate the following matrix:

```
mat =
            1            2      0.70199
            1            6      0.46313
            1            7      0.98821
            1           12      0.15645
            1           13      0.67037
            1           16      0.86966
            2            8      0.63491
            2            9     0.076501
            2           15      0.55076
            2           17      0.44727
            2           19      0.30587
            3            5      0.91502
            3           10      0.97322
            3           20      0.48231
            4            3      0.45633
            4            4      0.12363
            4           11      0.18319
            4           14      0.36045
            5            1      0.36708
            5           18      0.63084
```

and the result was:

```
result =
            1            7      0.98821
            1           12      0.15645
            1           13      0.67037
            1           16      0.86966
            2            9     0.076501
            2           15      0.55076
            2           17      0.44727
            2           19      0.30587
            4            3      0.45633
            4            4      0.12363
            4           11      0.18319
            4           14      0.36045
```

Comment: Thanks Amro.  For some reason, your code does not work correctly for the example above.  I have modified unique fnc to use 2 cols instead of one but it is still picking up 5555 (which should be dropped as it has count <4 rows).  Shall appreciate.

Comment: @Maddy: well it wasn't clear from your initial description whether you wanted to keep rows with less than 4 unique ID occurrences.. Anyways see my recent edit for the fix

Comment: thanks!  I need to understand accumarray more thoroughly.  I designed a new approach using reshape() etc but your solution is much shorter and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient implementation you have seen, but it works:

```
a = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ];
b = unique(a);

for i = 1:length(b)
   c = b(i);
   ind = find(a==c);
   last4 = ind(end-1:end) %adjust how many elements you want
end
```

Obviously, if you have a matrix you'd have to add the column index if the things you care about

Answer (score 0):

```
X=[];
id=ones(size(mat,1),1)==1;
for n=1:4
   [~, m, ~]=unique(mat(id,1:2),'rows');
   X=[X; mat(m,:)];
   id(m)=0;
end
return X
```

(In your example answer you didn't return any of the 5555 rows, but I assume you want them.)

Comment: Hi Cyborg, thanks for the reply.  I left out '5555' because it had <4 rows as desired in the example!